# How to produce an array that is the difference between two arrays of json objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is driving me crazy.

I'm trying to do a get an array that is the difference between two arrays containing json objects.

I can do this easily with arrays of primitive values, by using sets.  I mainly come from a Java background not JavaScript and this seems annoyingly difficult.

```
const available = [{time:1, chargable: true}, {time:2, chargable: false}, {time:3, chargable: true},{time:4, chargable: true}];
const booked = [{time:2, chargable: false}, {time:3, chargable: false}, {time:4, chargable: false}];

const remainingAvailable = findRemainingAvailable(available, booked)
```

I want `remainingAvailable` to contain: `[{time:1, chargable: true}]`

How do I do that (ideally using funky functions like filter etc)?

Comment: So even if the `chargable` state is different, as long as the `time` is the same it's considered the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a set for booked times and filter the available times.

```js
const
    findRemainingAvailable = (a, b) => {
        const booked = new Set(b.map(({ time }) => time))
        return a.filter(({ time }) => !booked.has(time))
    },
    available = [{ time: 1, chargable: true }, { time: 2, chargable: false }, { time: 3, chargable: true }, { time: 4, chargable: true }],
    booked = [{ time: 2, chargable: false }, { time: 3, chargable: false }, { time: 4, chargable: false }],
    remainingAvailable = findRemainingAvailable(available, booked);

console.log(remainingAvailable);
```

Comment: Thank you, I think what I was missing was the destructuring on the parameter to filter.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your provided data and expected output, it seems like you do not care about the `chargable` state of the objects, but only want to compare them based on the value of `time`.

Then, all you need is to create a mapped array containing all the `time` values in the `booked` array, and then filter the `available` array of objects, only keeping entries whose `time` is not found in the mapped array:

```js
const available = [{time:1, chargable: true}, {time:2, chargable: false}, {time:3, chargable: true},{time:4, chargable: true}];
const booked = [{time:2, chargable: false}, {time:3, chargable: false}, {time:4, chargable: false}];

function findRemainingAvailable(available, booked) {
  // Only compare based on time
  const bookedTimes = booked.map(x => x.time);

  return available.filter(({ time }) => !bookedTimes.includes(time));
}

const remainingAvailable = findRemainingAvailable(available, booked);
console.log(remainingAvailable);
```

Comment: Thank you, I think what I was missing was the destructuring on the parameter to filter.